# TV show about teens with "magic armor" fighting a villainess

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for the name of this TV show from the mid 90s. I don't remember it very well but here is what I can recall:

1. Live action.
2. Heroes were present day teens who were thrown into the action, one male, one female.
3. The villain I best remember - a villain across multiple episodes, was a mid-aged female.
4. When I was young I would strap a soccer/football shin guard onto my forearm and pretend I had some "magic armor" from the show.
5. I think the "magic armor" augmented strength, but not sure.
6. The heroes had the "armor", but the villainess from #3 had "armor" too. Hers may have been better than theirs.

Comment: The Power Rangers?

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208486/90s-tv-series-where-a-boy-goes-to-another-dimension-through-portal-near-power-l (which is newer and has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

This could be [*Spellbinder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)). It matches on most of the points mentioned:

It's live action, about present-day (90s) teens and other-world teens, mostly about a boy and a girl, though I *think* the girl isn't from our world.

Is has special suits the spellbinders wear which let them do things like fire bolts of electricity.

It has a baddie (Ashka) who plays the same role in both otherwise unrelated seasons. I remember her suit being more powerful than the others but it's been a long time and I could be wrong. You can see it about 20 seconds into the trailer here:

Comment: I remember Spellbinder, and I think this is the show OP is looking for. Note in particular that OP said they used something strapped to their forearm - the bits of the armour that fired energy bolts were indeed attached to the Spellbinders' forearms. Also - I think in series 1 Ashka had just a standard issue suit, but series 2 had her trying to use our world's technology to build a new, more powerful suit. I know *someone* in series 2 was trying to do that, anyway.

Comment: This was exactly what my immediate thought was. If I recall correctly, Ashka actually became sort of a semi-goodie in the second (third?) series because there was an even worse baddie out there. I absolutely loved this show as a teen, though admittedly I now mainly remember it for the massive teenage crush I had on Zbych Trofimiuk (who played Paul). So massive that I can still recall the somewhat unusual name ‘Zbych Trofimiuk’ now, twenty years later.